# Why is my variables not being added to my 2 list?

Tags: python, list, function, return, new-operator

Even and odd list

```
import random
even_numbers = []
odd_numbers = []

def oddandeven (numbers_list):
    original_list = [random.randint (1,10) for x in range(0,10)]
    print ('Original list:',original_list)
    
    for numbers_list in original_list:
        if numbers_list % 2 == 0:
            even_numbers.append(numbers_list)
            even_numbers.sort()
            return even_numbers
    
        else:
            odd_numbers.append(numbers_list)
            odd_numbers.sort()
            return odd_numbers
        
print (oddandeven(even_numbers))
print (oddandeven(odd_numbers))
```

My output of even and odd lists only consists of single variables, not a list despite the append function.
How do you output them into two lists, one consisting of even numbers, and the other odd numbers?

I am new to programming and would appreciate the help :)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.  Please tag whatever language this is.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it

```
import random
even_numbers = []
odd_numbers = []
original_list = [random.randint (1,10) for x in range(0,10)]

def oddandeven ():
    print (f'Original list: {original_list}')
    
    for a in original_list:
        if a % 2 == 0:
            even_numbers.append(a)
            even_numbers.sort()
        else:
            odd_numbers.append(a)
            odd_numbers.sort()

    print(odd_numbers)
    print(even_numbers)

oddandeven()
```